# Memory allocation for converting a large 2d array to a 1d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

A is a 2d array and data is 1d array

```
double **A, *data;
```

fullsize is 9222,
memory allocation:

```
A = (double **)malloc((fullsize)*sizeof(double *));         //allocate memory dynamically for matrix A
for (i = 0; i < fullsize; i++)
    A[i] = (double *)malloc((2 * fullsize)*sizeof(double));

data = (double *)malloc((fullsize*fullsize)*sizeof(double *));
```

conversion logic:

```
{
    for (int n = 0; n<fullsize; n++)
    for (int m = 0; m<fullsize; m++)
    {
        data[n*fullsize + m] = A[n][m];
    }
}
```

error log:

```
The thread 0xad80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00F5E6E9 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x69E65000.

The program '[50964] ConsoleApplication1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Why do you use `malloc` in c++?

Comment: because the data is large. @Muhammad

Comment: data = (double *)malloc((fullsize*fullsize)*sizeof(double *)); You should use sizeof( double ) here.

Comment: Large data doesn't mean `malloc`. Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` by default to get your code correct first. If you come from programming C, put everything you know on hold and pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: see the comment from @olgierdh. Also, is any of the malloc returning 0 (failing)? Anyway I would not use malloc to allocate memory in C++

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating `data` using size of `double` pointer:

```
data = (double *)malloc((fullsize*fullsize)*sizeof(double *));
//                                                        ^
```

It should be allocated using `sizeof(double)` instead.

You can avoid using `malloc` in C++ by using `vector`s. If you want exact sizes on allocations, use `new double[...]` instead. In either case you will end up with more readable code:

```
double **A = new double*[fullsize];
for (int i = 0 ; i != fullsize ; i++) {
    A[i] = new double[fullsize];
}
double *data = new double[fullsize*fullsize];
```

Comment: I tried `sizeof(double)` its still giving the same error, I need arrays for conversion into Eigen matrix;

Comment: @Sanju Did you try `new`? Also, `2` in `malloc((2 * fullsize)*sizeof(double))` looks suspicious. Is your matrix not square?

Comment: Is any of the malloc failing (returning 0)?

Comment: It seems that your malloc returns nullptr somewhere. Also @dasblinkenlight is right you don't need the 2*fullsize. Try compiling your application using clang with:  
  
`-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O1 -g`  

Plus you can do this trick if you want to:  
`double* data = ( double* ) malloc( fullsize * fullsize * sizeof( double ) );  
 double** A = static_cast< double** >( &data );`

This way you will have both views onto one continuous memory block.